# Compare two duration time and minutes in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a query where the condition is when time start fall or started from 22:00 until 6:00 will do some calculation
type of time start and time to is long text

however my query is not working properly. Any help or suggestion is really much appreciated

My query is like this

```
 CASE 
When   (t.timestart ='6' or t.timestart  <='22')  
THEN    
//do calculation
END AS val1
```

expected result is when  time start and time to started from 22:00 until 6:00 will do some calculation

Ex:

timestart - 7:00 falls in condition
timestart - 23 doesntfall condition

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and expected results ?

Comment: What data types do `timestart` and `timeto` have?

Comment: What does it mean for "timeto" to start in some range?

Comment: timestart and timeto is longtext

Comment: Bad decision. First change the schema and use an appropriate [date/time type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with CAST function :

```
CASE
    WHEN CAST(t.timestart AS TIME) >= '06:00:00' 
        AND CAST(t.timeto AS TIME) <= '22:00:00'
    THEN
        //do calculation
END AS val1
```